# Attributing variables to msg.payload in Node-Red

Tags: json, node-red

```
output = {
    "_id": id_rev._id,
    "_rev": id_rev._rev,
}

msg.payload = output;

return msg;
```

I'm trying to assign data from other Json variables into a single msg.payload in NodeRed.

But instead of assigning them, the output exits the node empty. That doesn't happen if I try to assign, for example, any string like "Hello World!".

Comment: You haven't shown where the `id_rev` object is coming from. Edit the question to include a lot more details

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided you have an extra comma. This would cause the javascript to fail. Try it with the following instead:

```
output = {
    "_id": id_rev._id,
    "_rev": id_rev._rev
}

msg.payload = output;

return msg;
```

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to take it out when writing the comment, but there's actually more attributes to the object, that's why the comma.